# Capture and send jpeg images from Raspberry Pi to PC socket python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi

I would like to send images captured from Rasberry pi camera to the PC live like a stream but not a stream as I dont have so much bandwidth.
The code I have now is.

**Client**

```
import io
import cv2
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image
import numpy

# Start a socket listening for connections on 0.0.0.0:8000 (0.0.0.0 means
# all interfaces)
cv2.namedWindow('Network Image')
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8200))
server_socket.listen(0)

# Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
try:
    while True:
        # Read the length of the image as a 32-bit unsigned int. If the
        # length is zero, quit the loop
        image_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        if not image_len:
            break
        # Construct a stream to hold the image data and read the image
        # data from the connection
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))
        # Rewind the stream, open it as an image with PIL and do some
        # processing on it
        image_stream.seek(0)
        image = Image.open(image_stream).convert('RGB')
        open_cv_image = numpy.array(image)
        open_cv_image = open_cv_image[:, :, ::-1].copy()
        cv2.imshow('Network Image',open_cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        print('Image is %dx%d' % image.size)
        image.verify()
        print('Image is verified')
finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

**Server**

```
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

# Connect a client socket to my_server:8000 (change my_server to the
# hostname of your server)
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('192.168.2.225', 8200))

# Make a file-like object out of the connection
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
try:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.framerate=15
        camera.resolution = (480, 480)
        # Start a preview and let the camera warm up for 2 seconds
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(2)

        # Note the start time and construct a stream to hold image data
        # temporarily (we could write it directly to connection but in this
        # case we want to find out the size of each capture first to keep
        # our protocol simple)
        start = time.time()
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg'):
            # Write the length of the capture to the stream and flush to
            # ensure it actually gets sent
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream.tell()))
            connection.flush()
            # Rewind the stream and send the image data over the wire
            stream.seek(0)
            connection.write(stream.read())
            # If we've been capturing for more than 30 seconds, quit
            if time.time() - start > 30:
                break
            # Reset the stream for the next capture
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
    # Write a length of zero to the stream to signal we're done
    connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

Can I make this efficient in someway?
Ideally I'd like to capture a frame and save as a jpeg and transfer to the client at 30 FPS.
Right now I get around 8 FPS.

Comment: try using threads

Comment: If you can accept a delay of 200 ms you may use buffers.

Comment: Take the write to the socket out of the server to test your raw acquisition frame rate. Likewise take the read from the camera out of your server and send static frames over the wire to see your raw transfer rate. Then think about optimising. By the way, are you using wireless or wired Ethernet?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm using Ethernet.

Comment: I did some tests last year with a USB Gigabit Ethernet adapter plugged into my Raspi and it gets nearly double the speed of the built-in 100Mbit/s adapter - so not true GiGabit speeds but still double. It is a TRENDnet TU3-ETG USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter available for £15 on Amazon UK. It doesn't need any software patches, drivers or anything - works out of the box.

Comment: @farbiondriven can u send me an example of how I can do this with the buffer ??

Comment: You write the stream content in an array, then you send it in the socket every 3 or 4 frames.

Comment: Dud you try benchmarking just the acquisition, and then separately, just the transfer like I suggested?

Comment: @MarkSetchell kinda. So no matter which resolution and framerate I choose the pi3 was able to only save 2 FPS(using camera.record and camera.capture functions) to the device which I could send over Ethernet. But The workaround I found was to use mjpeg streamer and use a python code to just grab frames. Its a hack but it works. Let me know if u have another idea

Answer (score 0):

use

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg', use_video_port = True):
```